# non-www. to www. *but* for unknown TLD

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect

Does anyone know of a RewriteRule that will redirect a non-www. to www. version, ***but*** without knowing what the TLD will be?, i.e. a rule for...

```
http://example.com -> http://www.example.com
http://example.co.uk -> http://www.example.co.uk
http://example.fr -> http://www.example.fr
http://example.de/something.html -> http://www.example.de/something.html
```

I'd rather have one neat rule, rather than listing out all the possible TLDs, but not sure how to do it, and I searched but can't find anything similar.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple actually.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The condition checks if the domain name does not start with `www.` and if that's true redirects the complete request with the `www.` attached this time.

Comment: Thanks Ravi, just needed a % before {REQUEST_URI}.  I'm not sure why someone voted this down, seemed like a fair question to ask to me and not answered previously as far as I could see.